# Determine whether the following series converges or diverges. Justify your answer.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I need some real help with this question. I am asked to determine if$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^2}{(3n-1)^4}$$converges or diverges. I have tried this question for many days already and I am so stressed out from it. So what I did was that I used the integral test and then I used partial fraction decomposition to break it down. Then I tried to integrate the outcome but it was very hard to derive the correct answer. Please, could anyone give me some help?

Comment: Do you know the convergence rule for $p$-series? Can you find a comparison to a $p$-series?

Comment: ya i learnt that already, but i am not so sure how that will help me in solving this question?:/

Comment: You should notice that $n^2 / (3n - 1)^4 < 1/n^2$

Comment: Hi thank you! I was so fixated on trying to use another method that I didnt see this. Thank you for the help!:)

Comment: No problem. The other methods seem more useful at first because they provide a definite algorithm, but you may find that with practice you will find the comparison test gets more useful because you will be able to spot comparisons more easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The series converges because$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{n^2}{(3n-1)^4}}{\frac1{n^2}}=\frac1{3^4}$$and the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}$ converges.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for this! :) Really cleared my doubts.

Comment: The condition $\frac1{3^4}\neq0$ is not requested for convergence.

Comment: Note that it suffices that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{n^2}{(3n-1)^4}}{\frac1{n^2}}=\frac1{3^4}$ indeed we can also prove convergence by $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{n^2}{(3n-1)^4}}{\frac1{n^{\frac32}}}=0$

Comment: @gimusi I agree and I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$\frac{n^2}{(3n-1)^4}\sim\frac1{3^4n^2} $$

then use [limit comparison test](https://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/SandS/SeriesTests/limit_comparison.html) with $\sum \frac1{n^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the denominator simpler first, by focusing on the leading term, rather than dealing with all its minor features.  In this case, just note that $3n-1 \ge 2n$ for $n\ge 1$.  Then
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{(3n-1)^4} \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{16n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{96}.
$$
Clearly it doesn't much matter what's going on down there after the leading order... it could be $(3n - \log n)^4$, or $(3n-\sqrt{n})^4$, or whatever.  You want to find a simple bound and reduce the complexity as soon as possible.